# Blender 2.90.0 scripting (copying selected mesh)

Tags: scripting

I'm completely new to coding in Phython. Especially blender scripting. I was googling all the possible ways to copy a selected mesh. But none of the code seems to work as it was for 2.7 or 2.8 blender version. As well as I like to add the new copy of the mesh to selected place. Wether it's underneath the selected mesh, or above. I'd like to as well scale the copy down.